# OOP design suggestion for inheritance

Tags: oop, design-patterns

```
abstract class db{
    // return an handle to db
}

class type extends db{
    // code that uses db
}

abstract class limits extends db{
    // code that DOES NOT use db
}

class otherclass extends limits{
    // code that use db and limits
}
```

As you can see, I need db in all classes except limits. But limits is parent for classes that use db.
I think this is not the correct design pattern, since I extend db in limits just to have db available for children. Or is it?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that the only reason for the limits class to exsists? In that case: Get rid of that class

Comment: No Vincent. the limits class does other jobs needed by children.

Comment: Why does it extend the `db` if it doesn't "use" it - and surely use indicates compose not inherit. WHy does limit need a base class/interface?

Comment: Why does "code that *uses* DB" *extend* DB? Seems like a case for composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on unstated requirements, you would be better off with *composition* instead of inheritance, in this case.

```
class db {
    // returns db handle
}

class type {
    private db; // type can now use db
}

class limits {
    // does something
}

class otherclass {
     private limits;
     private db;      // can use limits and db
}
```

Comment: +1. Mostly because four classes without any inheritence between them is just beautiful :-) Subclassing is the most over-rated/over-used aspect of OOP.

Comment: Seems you're perfectly right md4. I'm really a novice in OOP. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You said " I need db in all classes except limits." which indicates you should compose (or contain) a db not inherit from it. See md4's answer.

You need to think about why you might have abstract classes - this is usually because you want to "program to an interface" to coin a phrase.

Perhaps `db` and `limits` are two different things - think single responsibility...

```
abstract class db {
    // returns db handle
}

abstract class limits {
    // does something
}

class otherclass : extends limits,  db {
}
```

**...edit start...**
Clearly for some specific OO languages like Java and C# `limits` and `db` would need to be `interface`s rather than classes. The OP didn't specify a language.
**...edit end...**

Think about the using code - consider writing a few unit tests to see what it looks like. Think about what must change together and what should be decoupled.

Comment: I prefer your answer. It gives the OP more to ponder.

Comment: Having said that, your `otherclass` seems to be attempting multiple inheritance, not something to my knowledge supported by Java (what I presume the OP to be using).

Comment: True - but there was no language tag... I spell "interface" "abstract class" in C++ but then I don't say "extends"

Comment: I used abstract because I don't want to create an istance of db. It wouldn't make sense except in classes defined as children in my example. But I agree with the both of you that it looks much better your way. as per the language.. it's PHP

Comment: This may give you a few more things to think about: "KISSing SOLID goodbye" http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1957